# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' when using virtualenv

Tags: bash, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have created a python3 virtual environment "test" inside "~/.virtualenvs" using virualenv. But, I got the following error when I tried to activate.

```
bash: /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `(' 
bash: /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/activate: line 4: `deactivate () {'
```

I tried to use virtualenv on ubuntu container and cloud9 ide also but got the same error.

Comment: we need to see the code inside virtualenvs

Comment: What was the exact command line you ran to activate it? This seems like incorrect activation, if anything, or possibly sourcing the wrong script for your shell (though `activate` should match `bash`).

Comment: I run the following command: source ~/.virtualenvs/test/bin/activate

Comment: Here is the command and corresponding output to create "test" environment:
    $ virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/test
    Using base prefix '/usr'
    New python executable in /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python3
    Also creating executable in /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python
    Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, It works if I run ` source /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/activate` from root.

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger and @John Joe, I have figured out that the cause of the problem was in my .bash_alias file. There was an alias "deactivate" that I created long before to deactivate conda environment but I forgot that. And in all my ubuntu containers and pcs I used the same ~.bash_alias file. After deleting that from the .bash_alias file the command `source ~/.virtualenvs/test/bin/activate` works fine. I am extremely sorry for wasting your time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the question is being viewed frequently. Even though I put a comment regarding the solution, I think, it is better to answer here.
I have figured out that the cause of the problem was in my `~.bash_alias` file. There was an alias "deactivate" that I created long before to deactivate conda environment but I forgot that. And in all my ubuntu containers and pcs I used the same `~.bash_alias` file. After deleting that from the `~.bash_alias` file the command `source ~/.virtualenvs/test/bin/activate` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an alias in your .bashrc file, that's why bash takes deactivate  like a command, not like a function

instead

```
deactivate() {
```

use this

```
function deactivate() {
```

Comment: "**Maybe**"? That's just what the OP said in a comment 7 months ago. You should at least acknowledge that.