# Why the error : "cannot import name 'balanced_accuracy' from 'sklearn.metrics' " is more complicated than it should?

Tags: python, bash, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, conda

I'm trying to do a multiclass classification project on COVID-19 imbalanced dataset using jupyter notebooks on kaggle, my code is :

```
import random
import gc
import numpy as np
from numpy import asarray
import itertools

train_dir='/kaggle/input/pandemic2/Training/Training'
test_dir='/kaggle/input/pandemic2/Testing/Testing'

train_covid=['/kaggle/input/pandemic2/Training/Training/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 'COVID' in I]
train_normal=['/kaggle/input/pandemic2/Training/Training/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 'Normal' in I]
train_pneumonia=['/kaggle/input/pandemic2/Training/Training/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(train_dir) if 'MERS' or 
                                                                                                    'SARS'or 
                                                                                                    'Bacterial' or  
                                                                                                    'Chlamydia' or 
                                                                                                    'Influenza' or 
                                                                                                    'Klebsiella' or 
                                                                                                    'Legionella' or 
                                                                                                    'Mycoplasma' or 
                                                                                                    'Pneumocystis' or 
                                                                                                    'Streptococcus' or 
                                                                                                    'Varicella' in I]

test_imgs=['/kaggle/input/pandemic2/Testing/Testing/{}'.format(i) for i in os.listdir(test_dir)]

train_imgs=train_covid[:] + train_normal[:] + train_pneumonia[:]
random.shuffle(train_imgs)

del train_covid
del train_normal
del train_pneumonia
gc.collect()

nrows=150
ncolumns=150
channels= 3
def read_and_process_image (list_of_images):
   x=[]
   y=[]
   for image in list_of_images:
      x.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR),(nrows, ncolumns), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))
      if 'Normal' in image:
        y.append(0)
      elif 'COVID' in image:
        y.append(1)
      else:
        y.append(2)
   return x,y

x,y= read_and_process_image(train_imgs)

del train_imgs
gc.collect()

x=np.array(x)
print(x.shape)
y=np.array(y)
print(y.shape)

import sklearn
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold  
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy

from keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2
conv_base= InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(150,150,3))

model=models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

from keras import optimizers
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4), metrics= ['categorical_accuracy'])

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                            rotation_range=40,
                            width_shift_range=0.2,
                            height_shift_range=0.2,
                             shear_range=0.2,
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             horizontal_flip=True  )
val_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True,random_state=1)
scores = cross_val_score(model, x, y, cv=5, scoring= "balanced_accuracy")

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(x,y, stratify=y, test_size=0.20, random_state=2)
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, stratify=y_train, train_size=0.8, random_state=2)

from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train=to_categorical(y_train,3)
print('Shape of training lables is:', y_train.shape)
y_val=to_categorical(y_val,3)
print('Shape of validation lables is:', y_val.shape)
y_test=to_categorical(y_test,3)
print('Shape of test labels is:', y_test.shape)

for index, (train_indices, val_indices) in enumerate(skf.split(x, y)):
   print ("Training on fold " + str(index+1) + "/" + str(n_splits))
   
   # Generate batches from indices
   xtrain, xval = x[train_indices], x[val_indices]
   ytrain, yval = y[train_indices], y[val_indices]

   ntrain=len(x_train)
   nval=len(x_val)
   batch_size=32

   train_generator=train_datagen.flow(x_train,y_train, batch_size=batch_size)
   val_generator=val_datagen.flow(x_val,y_val,batch_size=batch_size)

   print ("Training new iteration on " + str(xtrain.shape[0]) + " training samples, " +     str(xval.shape[0]) + " validation samples, this may take while...")
   history=model.fit(train_generator,
   steps_per_epoch=ntrain//batch_size,
   epochs=80,
   validation_data=(val_generator),
   validation_steps=nval//batch_size,
   verbose=2)
print('\nBalanced Accuracy:', mterics.balanced_accurcay*100, '%')
```

when I run the code it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-45c4c9070141> in <module>
6 from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
7 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
----> 8 from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy
9 
10 #Download the model

ImportError: cannot import name 'balanced_accuracy' from 'sklearn.metrics' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py)
```

I've tried so many solutions like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349331/valueerror-balanced-accuracy-is-not-a-valid-scoring-value-in-scikit-learn), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59377154/balanced-accuracy-is-not-a-valid-scoring-value-in-scikit-learn), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919980/cannot-import-name-balanced-accuracy-score) and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097709/cannot-import-name-balanced-accuracy-score) but [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57966943/solved-how-do-i-import-scikit-learn-in-a-jupyter-notebook) has lead me to another complicated issue because whenever I run the command `conda activate myenv` it gives me the error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
- bash
- fish
- tcsh
- xonsh
- zsh
- powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Tackling this issue by [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078923/why-my-conda-activate-does-not-work-though-i-have-a-list-of-conda-environments) it [thoroughly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246350/conda-activate-not-working) and trying what is provided in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507519/python-activate-conda-env-through-shell-script) lead me to the following error message:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'  /bin/bash: -c: line 0: `/opt/conda/bin/conda init <bash>'.
```

I have tried these solutions, [1](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1831) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965734/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-when-using-virtualenv) but had no luck !!

Then, when I got stuck and felt trapped, I tried to follow the [conda official documentation](https://docs.conda.io/_/downloads/conda/en/master/pdf/) to create a virtual environment with all the needed packages but I ran into the same error above stating that **my shell is not properly configured to activate the new virtualenv** !!

Again, I went back to do the simple solutions by reverting to the first version of my base environment by doing `conda list revisions` `conda install --revision=0` and updating it but the error persists and still preventing me from using balanced_accuracy and other useful metrics.

I also tried to create a new jupyter notebook and start from scratch by updating my packages but they were already updated to the most recent versions !!

**I believe that I'm running the set of configuration commands in the wrong order** because my jupyter kernel and environment is a complete mess now.

It would be highly appreciated if someone can ***guide me to the best practices*** in setting up the environments for a deep learning task.

**BTW:** the solutions suggested manipulating the `bashrc` file are a bit confusing to me and I don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: Hmm.. Are you sure you want `from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy` and not `from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score` (per https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score) ? Also, in my experience, it's best to never install _anything_ into your base environment - create a new conda environment for every 'task' and if it gets borked you won't have any issues starting again.

Comment: @jared_mamrot yes, I'm sure !! mainly, I need balanced_accuracy but since it didn't work I tried balanced_accuracy_score instead, anyways I think the problem is in the sklearn.metrics.

Comment: You can't import `'balanced_accuracy'` because it is not a method, it is a scorer associated with `balanced_accuracy_score()`, as per https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.20.html#id33 and https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values.

Comment: Also you are posting two separate questions. Remove the conda issue to a new question or this question is likely to be closed as having no focus.